# macbuntu - is it a linux distro or a desktop or a theme?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubuntu

After 25+ years of using various versions of Windows, to experiment with non-Windows OS, I bought a pre-installed Ubuntu laptop from System76 around 6 months ago and a friend of mine installed Kubuntu (over the Ubuntu). Since then, I have become a fan of Kubuntu (vs Windows): speed is great, no worries about Viruses, Kaffeine is better than anything I have seen on Windows or Mac, etc..

So far, I didn't really need to learn Linux basics at all (i.e. bash / other scripting) - not even any basic terms. If the Software Center couldn't install any application, I read the instructions on the net, followed them diligently, occasionally took me 3-4 hours to get it working (e.g. Netflix), but by-and-large quite smooth installation.

Now, I want to convert all my older Windows laptops to Linux and was deciding between various distros (Mint vs Kubuntu vs NetRunner) vs desktops vs themes vs icons etc. and came across MacBuntu (from NoobsLab) which I am quite interested to explore.

I had some basic questions:

1. What is the basic difference between a desktop vs theme (in the context of Linux) vs icons? I tried to google a lot, but there are no clear answers - and almost everywhere a desktop vs theme vs icons seem to be used interchangeably or assumes that the reader of the article knows Linux already.
2. Is a linux distro tied to a particular desktop, e.g. Ubuntu has Unity, but to use KDE I have to use Kubuntu?
3. Is MacBuntu: a desktop like KDE / Unity, or is it a theme or an icon? (I suspect it is not a distro per se, because it's website says "Mac OS X transformation pack is ready for Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr" ), but just wanted to be sure
4. There appears to be a lot of information about installing MacBuntu if a PC has Ubuntu on it. Would my current regular Kubuntu applications (like say Kaffeine) work after MacBuntu is installed, or is MacBuntu designed to run Mac applications ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Desktop has a set of utilities tied to it, e.g., in kde you have kate as text editor, while in unity it's gedit. Theme only alters look of windows or icons

2) Distro comes with default desktop but is not limited to default one. I use Ubuntu, but I've been using openbox, blackbox, gnome, kde(which is default in kubuntu), lxde, and motif, interchangeably. My older laptop can't handle gnome properly with Fedora, so I've been using cinnamon desktop (which is default for Linux Mint ) there

3) MacBuntu is a theme found on noobslab website if I am not mistaken. I used it with unity and in gnome. Here's gnome-terminal in gnome with mac windows controls i use right now

[image]

4) Mac applications are different from linux applications, hence you cant run them. You'd need virtual machine with mac os x or darwin for that

You might also be interested in [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/18078/295286)

And here is my openbox desktop . I am using tint2 launcher bar at the bottom, OS X-like wallpaper, and a theme with very tiny dot icons for close, maximise, and minimize buttons; as you can see window borders also get silver tint. The start/sun icon on the panel is actually a script shortcut (.desktop file), for which I used an icon from high-contrast theme from ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between theme and icon in the context of Linux?

Comment: Well, and icon is a single image file, usually png. If you know where that icon is stored you can alter just that icon without changing the overall theme. A theme is a set of many icons and color settings

Comment: Let me also show you my openbox desktop, brb